# Sync local mysql with remote mssql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sequelize.js, database-replication, sequelize-cli

I'm developing a website with nodejs and mysql.

My client has got an sql server database in their buildings. The sql server DB is the main data source but it can not be used as the website's data source.

So I have to regularly sync the two.

Any changes made by my client to their mssql db will be replicated to the website's mysql db, and changes to the mysql db (from users) must be replicated to the mssql server.

They're willing to accept a 30 minutes gap between syncs.

I'm using sequelize and I'm wondering if it's possible to use migration strategies for that so any input will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It appears that the client was sold something that was already in stock and now you are trying to load a sheep and a lion on the same boat to get it over the river, You should have really used SQL Server as your database, anyway the only option to do a cross platform sync with SQL Server is to use a third-party application called Attunity, it will do a real-time replication and can do replication between any two different clients , but it will cost money.

Comment: Using SQL Server on our end is still an option for us. The answers here will tell us if we should do that. Right now we don't have information on mssql pricing (with replication support).

Comment: You only have to pay for MS SQL Server licences MS SQL Replication is a free tool that comes with it, I think you are better off buying SQL Server license rather than going for a cheaper DB option and then paying a lot of money to third-parties to replicate data. Attunity does a really good job but they are not cheap.

Comment: Another important point is that the DB only has 10 tables tops that need to be synced. So manual sync is still an option and will give us full control.

Comment: Only 10 tables and the customer is willing to have a 30 min lag, hmmm yea I think I would start with an ETL process first too.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help !

Comment: SymmetricDS would work and provides and open source and a supported version.  https://www.jumpmind.com/products/symmetricds/overview